# КАК вывести данные

Tags: php

как вывести данные`<?php $res = mysqli_query ($link, "select(`name`) from`vse`WHERE`
id`=1;"); $reg = mysqli_fetch_array($res); $total = $reg; echo
   ("$total"); ?>`

Comment: echo; var_dump; print, и т.д.

Comment: <?php $res = mysqli_query ($link, "select(`name`) from `vse` WHERE
   `id`=1;"); $reg = mysqli_fetch_array($res); $total = $reg; echo
   ("$total"); ?>

Comment: Сперва советую все-таки прочитать про основы PHP, даже если сейчас мы разберемся с вашей проблемой, то вы все равно далеко не уедете с такими знаниями.